# Is there some kind of service to queue api calls?

Tags: api, rest, queue, restful-architecture

I need to call the desk.com api to create cases when a customer completes a form on my site. However sometimes the API is down for maintenance (too often!) and my call will fail.

Presently I just write the details to a log on error and send myself an email. Then I create the case manually.

So I'm thinking to write some kind of message queue so instead of calling the api in-process, I can put the request in queue, then have some process work the queue and make the api calls. they way if the api call fails the process will just try again next scheduled interval.

Since there are so many web APIs in the world, I figure surely other people must be having the same problem. So are there some third-party solutions which effectively do what I'm trying to do? or some open-source project or something to deal with this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: How about using quartz.net?

Comment: you talking about this?
http://quartz-scheduler.org

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't url. Yes, the url you mentioned is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) is a fast, reliable, scalable, fully managed queue service. SQS makes it simple and cost-effective to decouple the components of a cloud application. You can use SQS to transmit any volume of data, at any level of throughput, without losing messages or requiring other services to be always available.

http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/